# How to display date using custom date format as per user locale

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

How can i display date using "moment.js" as per locale/language format(some languages follow different date formats for representation by default) and also able to customize that format as per needs:

```
e.g-> How can I show time using moment in this format: Sunday, January 1 2012 using moment.js which will be 2012年1月1日（日）in japan automatically. Moment library does not provide this customization by default.
i.e.-> Sunday, January 1 2012 (Using moment().format('LLLL'))?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to either update the existing moment locale format or get the locale format using moment, modify it as per your need and use. Steps below:

1. Get the format as per locale (or language) using moment.js.

   ```
   var localeFormat = moment.langData()._longDateFormat['LLLL'];//for moment v2.5.1
   ```
2. Modify the `localeFormat` as per custom format need.

   ```
   localeFormat.replace("LT","")
   ```

   which replaces the time values displayed in default locale format. For example:

   `Sunday, January 1 2012 12:45 pm` changes to `Sunday, January 1 2012`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve what you want is the following one:

1. Convert your *Moment* date into a *JavaScript* `Date`: `moment().toDate()`
2. Install **angular locale** which takes care of adjusting dates according to locales
3. Use `$filter('date')` when you need to display your date

Here you can find a guide to use internationalisation features of AngularJS [Angular i18n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n)

Answer (score 1):

you can customize it combining some of moment methods:

```
var moment = require('moment'); 
var date = moment().format('dddd, MMMM D YYYY');
console.log(date); // gives you the date in the format you need
```

Comment: @svarog this solution will not work for japanese locale. In japanese the time format is different.

Comment: detect if the local/language is japanese and provide a different format. goto [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/), scroll down, click the `japanese` button, the site should show you the japanese formatting

Comment: not a feasible solution to detect all languages and write a logic. anyways thanks. i found a solution.